# Do all spacecrafts first enter orbit and then transfer to another body?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, interstellar-travel, hohmann-transfer, low-energy-transfer

I would like to know if all spacecraft that have visited other planets first  orbited our own planet and then performed an orbital transfer, or if there have been some that just went directly to the other body. Also, I know that in theory, it's not required to enter orbit first. What are the pros/cons of doing that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll probably have to define what you mean by "enter orbit"; if you mean "performed at least one full orbit around Earth before leaving", that's one thing, but if you mean "reached speed relative to Earth sufficient to maintain orbit", that's another.

Comment: Duplicate of http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2675/why-should-space-probes-have-to-orbit-the-earth-before-being-launched-at-other-p and http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/637/do-any-launches-bypass-leo

Comment: See [this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/2682/265).

Comment: Also related: [What decides if a launch has to be done instantaneously or during a window?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/13086/415) and [What is the purpose of having a countdown during a rocket launch?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/1295/415) and to a lesser degree [Why have a 10 minute pause at T-4 minutes?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/2826/415)