# Why doesn't Ariane-5 lift off at T=0 seconds?

Tags: launch, launch-vehicle, launch-sequence, ariane

I have seen Ariane-5 lift off at T+07 seconds and not at (or close to) T=00 seconds. The following statement is from the [Ariane-5 User's Manual](https://www.arianespace.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Ariane5_Users-Manual_October2016.pdf) (Page 35, Section 2.3 - Typical Mission Profile):

> The engine of the cryogenic main core stage, Vulcain 2, is ignited at H0+1s. Until H0+7.05 seconds, the on-board computer checks the good behavior of the engine and authorizes the lift-off by the ignition of the two solid rocket boosters.

Most of the rockets to the best of my knowledge lift-off exactly (or around) T=00 seconds. Engine ignition takes place at somewhere like T-0x seconds. Then they attain full thrust close to T=0 seconds. Either SRBs ignite and hold down clamps release or the launch clamps release and lift-off take place. Why does Ariane-5 liftoff at T+7.05 seconds instead of T=0 seconds? Why so much delay? Instead, they could have started the engine ignition and the following checks a bit earlier (like engine ignition at T-6.05 seconds, and SRB ignition and lift-off at T=00 seconds). What is the reason for this? Are there any other launch vehicles which lift-offs well after T=00 seconds?

I thought all Ariane Space launch vehicles (Soyuz, Vega, Vega-C, etc.) do the same thing, but the following ascent profile of Soyuz shows that it lifts-off at T=00 seconds.

[image]

(Image from [Soyuz User's Manual](https://www.arianespace.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Soyuz-UsersManuel-issue2-Revision1-May18.pdf) - Page 35)

Comment: related: [What is the purpose of having a countdown during a rocket launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1295/what-is-the-purpose-of-having-a-countdown-during-a-rocket-launch) The time in the countdown corresponding to T=0 may correspond to anything you want, this is just a convention.

Comment: How do you define lift off? release from launchpad (last thing holding the launcher gone) ? nominal take off thrust reached ? Launcher not touching the launchpad (any part of the launcher? last umbilical released?)

Comment: @ManuH, According to me (and I think it will be for most of the people), lift-off is when there is no physical contact between the rocket and the ground facilities. I think two of your questions (in your second comment) mean the same, since rockets are released by the clamps only when full thrust is achieved after engine ignition.

Comment: I'm not quite sure clamps are released as soon as full thrust is achieved, especially for liquid propellant first stage such as delta VI heavy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Liftoff at T-0 is [common, but not universal](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19235/897). For Ariane 5, [T-0 is the moment of ignition of the Vulcain engine](http://spaceflight101.com/ariane-5-countdown-timeline/). In a nominal countdown, checkout takes 6 seconds, and the solids are ignited when checkout finishes, leading to liftoff at T+7. I suspect there is some flexibility built into this: if the checkout takes longer, this is easily accommodated and liftoff will be at T+8, for instance. T-0 is then the last fixed point in the countdown.

Ariane 5 does not reuse any infrastructure from other space agencies, so ESA/CNES/Arianespace were free to design a countdown that works for them.

The [sources](http://www.capcomespace.net/dossiers/espace_europeen/ariane/index.htm) I've found (not many) don't give a reason for this choice.