# What is the purpose of having a planned hold during a countdown for a rocket launch?

Tags: spacex, launch, nasa, falcon-9, ula

NASA had many with the space shuttle, ULA always had a planned hold at T-4 minutes, and yet other launch providers like SpaceX don't. What is the purpose of a planned hold, and why do some launchers perform them and others don't?

Comment: There at least a partial answer here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/why-have-a-10-minute-pause-at-t-4-minutes/2828#2828

Comment: There's also this one: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49148/why-does-spacex-crew-dragon-not-have-planned-holds . However it doesn't have any good answers. I think between the two this question is probably a duplicate. I'm surprised the second question doesn't have a quality answer.

Comment: Between the 2 it might be duplicate, if there was an good answer to the second one. However, there isnt @GdD

Comment: The second link doesnt in any way answer the question (the answwerer does not even seem to undertand what a planned hold is) so this isnt a duplicate @GdD